# Multithreading echo server

Tags: java, multithreading

Hello it is my first topic here.

I wrote some code to making connection client-server by sockets. As a client I mean opening terminal window and connection to this server by telnet. Application works as a server listening for requests from client on specified port. Every single connection is treat as a new thread. Once the connection is bound the client can send a message and gets an answer back as an echo.

The problem is I want to be informed when the client closes the terminal window (finish thread). I want to know id of this closed thread.

This is full code:

```
public class MultithreadEchoServer 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        int count=0;
        long[] ids = new long[10];

        try (ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(1234))
        {
            System.out.println("Listening...");

            while(true)
            {
                count++;
                Socket s = ss.accept();
                Runnable r = new MyThread(s, count);
                Thread t = new Thread(r);
                t.start();
                ids[count-1] = t.getId();

               if(Thread.activeCount() != count+1) 
                {
                    count = Thread.activeCount();
                    System.out.println("Client "+/*??thread's id??*/" left the session. Now connected: "+count);
                }

                System.out.println("Clients connected: "+count);
                System.out.println(ids[count-1]);

            }
        }
    }         
}

class MyThread implements Runnable
{
    private Socket s;
    private int count;
    private long id;
    InputStream io;
    OutputStream os;
    private PrintWriter pw;

    MyThread(Socket s, int count)
    {
        this.s = s;
        this.count = count;
    }

    public long getId()
    {
        id = Thread.currentThread().getId();
        return id;
    }

    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        try
        {
            io = s.getInputStream();
            os = s.getOutputStream();
        }
        catch (IOException e) {System.err.println(e);}
        try (Scanner sc = new Scanner(io))
        {
            pw = new PrintWriter(os, true);
            pw.println("Connected");
            while(sc.hasNextLine())
            {
                String line = sc.nextLine();
                System.out.println("Client "+count+": "+line);
                pw.println("Echo: "+line);     
            }
        }   
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why you donn't print Thread ID inside Thread execution with a `finally` statement after your `try` with resource statement :

```
try (Scanner sc = new Scanner(io))
{
    pw = new PrintWriter(os, true);
    pw.println("Connected");
    while(sc.hasNextLine())
    {
        String line = sc.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Client "+count+": "+line);
        pw.println("Echo: "+line);     
    }
}
finally {
    System.out.println("Client " + this.id + " left the session."");
}
```

**MultithreadEchoServer**

```
public class MultithreadEchoServer 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        int count=0;
        long[] ids = new long[10];

        try (ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(1234))
        {
            System.out.println("Listening...");

            while(true)
            {
                count++;
                Socket s = ss.accept();
                Runnable r = new MyThread(s, count);
                Thread t = new Thread(r);
                t.start();
                ids[count-1] = t.getId();

               if(Thread.activeCount() != count+1) 
                {
                    count = Thread.activeCount();
                    System.out.println("Now connected: "+count);
                }

                System.out.println("Clients connected: "+count);
                System.out.println(ids[count-1]);

            }
        }
    }         
}
```

**MyThread**

```
class MyThread implements Runnable
{
    private Socket s;
    private int count;
    private long id;
    InputStream io;
    OutputStream os;
    private PrintWriter pw;

    MyThread(Socket s, int count)
    {
        this.s = s;
        this.count = count;
    }

    public long getId()
    {
        id = Thread.currentThread().getId();
        return id;
    }

    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        try
        {
            io = s.getInputStream();
            os = s.getOutputStream();
        }
        catch (IOException e) {System.err.println(e);}
        try (Scanner sc = new Scanner(io))
        {
            pw = new PrintWriter(os, true);
            pw.println("Connected");
            while(sc.hasNextLine())
            {
                String line = sc.nextLine();
                System.out.println("Client "+count+": "+line);
                pw.println("Echo: "+line);     
            }
        }
        finally {
            System.out.println("Client " + this.id + " left the session."");
        }   
    }   
}
```